# NSFetchedResultsController delegates strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an NSFetchedResultsController linked with a tableView so i use the NSFetchedResultsController delegates to update the changes.

In (controllerWillChangeContent:) I try to store the indexes of the objects in the NSFetchedResultsController like this:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{

    NSLog(@"controllerWillChangeContent1");

    _indexesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (myObject* my_obj in [controller fetchedObjects]) {

        NSLog(@"name : %@  row : %d   section : %d", my_obj.name, [controller indexPathForObject:my_obj].row, [controller indexPathForObject:my_obj].section);

        NSIndexPath* idxPath = [controller indexPathForObject:my_obj];

        NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:my_obj.name forKey:@"name"];
        [dict setObject:idxPath forKey:@"index"];//it crashes on the deleted element
        [_indexesArray addObject:dict];

    }

    NSLog(@"controllerWillChangeContent2");

}
```

I know that i have a deleted item. I can loop through the objects (myObject) and read the names but it gives me a nil indexPath for the deleted object.

should NSFetchedResultsController preserve the indexes of the objects in (controllerWillChangeContent:)

Thank's

Comment: There is apples example, how to use `NSFetchedResultsController` with `UITableView` in `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` reference

Comment: Thank you for you reply but i store the indexes of the NSFetchedResultsController objects before the update for another purpose
and controllerWillChangeContent should not update the NSFetchedResultsController already as apple documentation

Answer (score 1):

In WillChange, the fetchedresultscontroller doesnt know what indexes the updated items will have yet. Thats why you have two more places where you the controller actually knows the indexes for the objects:

```
 - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath 

 - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
```

Comment: Thank's for your response
This is what I exactly want, I want to store the old indexes of the NSFetchedResultsController before the update but it seems that the indexes are already gone in WillChange because the deleted element have no index already in WillChange despite that it already existe and i can print it's name (but the index is nil).

Comment: @zizoodiesel The easiest way to do what you want, is to avoid letting the fetchedresultscontroller update your tableview and what you do is just to add the changes to two different MutableArrays in the above mentioned , one for "itemChanges" and one for "sectionChanges", and finally in "controllerDidChangeContent" you manually do the updates from the sectionChanges and Arraychanges you got. That way you have 100% control over what changes and what not :)

Comment: This is exactly what i do the need for storing the old indexes is because in (controllerDidChangeContent:) i am setting a limit to the controller like that
controller.fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 50; and then trying to remove the old indexes from the tableView sorted by date by adding their old indexes sored in WillChange to MutableArrays itemChanges and sectionChanges
this is a pretty complex task :)
If I only find another solution to do that

Comment: @zizoodiesel the fetchLimit does not limit the total limit, it only limits the actual fetches every fetch. That means if you have 1000 results, it will fetch all 1000 in batches of 50 per fetch. But the total will still be 1000. It is a complex task if its your first time doing it, and if not done correctly you will get crashes. But there are many good guides out there on how to do this. And regarding your limit, if you actually want the hard limit of 50 items, manual updates is the way to go.

Comment: As I so in many guides the problem with NSFetchedResultsController delegates if I have already for example 20 items the I fetch with fetchLimit 50 I would have 70 item in the [controller fetchedObjects].
My goal is if I have 50 new items I get rid of the old 20 items so it last only 50 items every task.
thank's for your assistance @Hauzin it must be a very good tutorial out there I will keep you informed :)

Comment: @zizoodiesel Yes then you must do it manually and it with get a little more complex as mentioned! NP, glad to help GL :)